# Extract characters in string following keyword and ending right before the other keyword

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table that looks like:

```
id
re|cid|13324242|
wa|cid|13435464|
fs|cid|2343532|
```

I want to extract information that is contained right after "|cid|" and before the following "|" element. That is:

```
13324242
13435464
2343532
```

I thought of substr() but there I don't know how to specify start and end element.

Comment: This is a really bad data model. Do you have a chance to fix that broken design before you proceed?

Comment: No, I can do what's needed in several iterations, but this is the original format I get utm-data in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `REGEXP_REPLACE` here (Standard SQL):

```sql
SELECT
    id,
    CASE WHEN id LIKE '%|cid|%'
         THEN REGEXP_REPLACE(id, '^.*\|cid\|(\d+)\|.*$', '\1') END AS cid
FROM yourTable;
```

The idea is to use a regex replacement to extract the `cid` value from the `id` column, should it be present (and if not, we would just return `NULL`).

Here is a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/VpNlRl/1) showing that the regex logic be correct.

Comment: This code extracts digits. What if there were digits and text characters?

Comment: Then use this more general pattern: `^.*\|cid\|(.*?)\|.*$` ... and keep the rest of the answer the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the third element (which appears to be the intention given the sample data), I would recommend `split()`:

```
select (split(id, '|')[ordinal(3)]
```